# What do the ALSA timestamping function return and how do the result relate to each other?

Tags: linux, audio, timestamp, alsa

There are several "hi-res" timestamping functions in ALSA:

```
snd_pcm_status_get_trigger_htstamp
snd_pcm_status_get_audio_htstamp
snd_pcm_status_get_driver_htstamp
snd_pcm_status_get_htstamp
```

I would like to understand what points in time the resulting functions represent.

My current understanding is that `trigger_htstamp` represents the time when stream was started/stopped/paused. `snd_pcm_status_get_trigger_htstamp` returns a constant value and when I add `audio_htstamp` to that value the result is very close to the current system time.

`audio_htstamp` seems to start from zero on my system and it is incremented by a value that is equal to the period size I use. Hence on my system it is a simple frame counter. If I understand ALSA correctly `audio_htstamp` can also work in different more accurate way depending on the system capabilities.

`driver_htstamp` I guess by the name is a timestamp generated by the audio driver.

**Question 1:** When is the timestamp `driver_htstamp` usually generated?

With `htstamp` I am really unsure where and when it is generated. I have a hunch that it may be related to DMA.

**Question 2:** Where is `htstamp` generated?

**Question 3:** When is `htstamp` generated?

**Question 4:** Is the assumption `audio_htstamp < htstamp < driver_htstamp` generally correct?

It seems like this with a little test [program](https://github.com/polaris/click) I wrote, but I want to verify my assumption.

I can not find this information in the ALSA documentation.

Comment: AFAIK this has something to do with synchronization of system clock and device clock.

Comment: That is what I guess too. Information on these functions is really terce. There does not seem to be many project making use of them as of now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just dug through the code for this stuff for my own purposes, so I figured I would share what I found.

The purpose of these timestamps is to allow you to determine subtle differences in the rate of different clocks; most importantly in this case the main system clock that Linux uses for general timekeeping compared with the different clock that determines the rate at which samples move in and out of the sound device. This can be very important for applications that need to keep audio from different hardware devices in sync, since the rates of different physical clocks are never exactly the same.

The technique used is sometimes called "cross-timestamping"; you capture timestamps from the clocks you want to compare as close to simultaneously as possible, and repeat this at regular intervals. There is usually some measurement error introduced, but some relatively simple filtering can get you a good characterization of the difference in the rate at which the clocks count.

The core PCM driver arranges to take a system clock timestamp as closely as possible to when an audio stream starts, and then it does a cross-timestamp between the system clock and audio clock (which can be measured in different ways) whenever it is asked to check the state of the hardware pointers for the DMA engine that moves samples around.

The default method of measuring the audio clock is via DMA hardware pointer comparsion. This isn't terribly precise, but over longer periods of time you can still get a good measure of the rate difference. At the start of `snd_pcm_update_hw_ptr0`, a system timestamp is captured; this will end up being `htstamp`. The DMA pointers are then checked, and if it's determined that they've moved since the last check, `audio_htstamp` is calculated based on the number of frames DMA has copied and the nominal frequency of the audio clock. Then, once all the DMA pointer update is done and right before `snd_pcm_update_hw_ptr0` returns, another system timestamp is captured in `driver_htstamp`. This isn't meant to be used when you're using the DMA hw_ptr method of calculating the `audio_htstamp` though.

If you happen to have an audio device using the HDAudio driver, you can use an alternate and much more precise method of measuring the audio clock. It supplies an extra operation callback called `get_time_info` that is used instead of the default method of capturing the system and audio timestamps. It the HDAudio case, it takes a system timestamp for `htstamp` as close to possible to when it reads an interal counter driven by the same clock source as the audio clock; this forms the `audio_htstamp`. Afterwards, the same DMA hw_ptr bookkeeping is done, but the code that translates the pointer movement into time is skipped. The `driver_htstamp` is still taken right before the routine ends, though; this is "to let apps detect if the reference tstamp read by low-level hardware was provided with a delay" as the comment says in the code. This is because there's no guarantee that the `get_time_info` callback is going to take a new system timestamp; it may have previously recorded an audio timestamp along with a system timestamp as part of an interrupt handler. In this case, the timestamps you get might not match with the available frames and delay frames counts calculated by hw_ptr bookkeeping, but the `driver_htstamp` will let you know the closest system time to when those calculations were made.

In any case, the code is designed in both cases to capture `htstamp` and `audio_htstamp` as closely together as possible, and for `htstamp - trigger_htstamp` to represent the amount of system time that passed during the period measured by `audio_htstamp` of the audio clock. You mostly shouldn't need to use `driver_htstamp`, but I guess it might be used with the USB Audio driver, as I think it and HDAudio are the only ones that do anything special with these interfaces right now.

The documentation for this, although it doesn't contain all the details you might want to know, is part of the kernel documentation: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/sound/alsa/timestamping.txt?v=4.9